# Ionic OneSignal Push Notification with default OS sound (no custom)

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, ionic3, onesignal

I am having problems receiving notifications on Androud and iOS devices. The notification arrives well but no sound is played. What is required is that when a notification is received, the default notification tone of the OS is reproduced.

The configuration I am using is: Ionic (v3) > OneSignal plugin, and the notifications are sent through the Rest API.